# MVC: How to get the controllers and their dependencies at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins

So I am building a MVC web application that is extendable with plugins. 
The plugins can be dropped into a folder and if the application is restarted they get loaded in. The problem I run into is that some/most of the controllers inside the plugins have constructors with parameters.
I already have a custom controller factory that can create the necessary controllers at runtime, but the problem lies in the registration of the controllers.
I currently have:

```
CustomControllerFactory factory = new CustomControllerFactory();
factory.RegisterFactoryMethod<MyController>(() => new MyController(_myDependecy));
```

with the controllerfactory as:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{

    private Dictionary<string, Func<IController>> _factoryMethods = new Dictionary<string, Func<IController>>();

    public void RegisterFactoryMethod<T>(Func<IController> factoryMethod)
                where T : IController
    {
        string controllerName = ConvertToControllerName<T>();

        if (_factoryMethods.ContainsKey(controllerName))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("FactoryMethod for controller '{0}'is already registered.", controllerName));

        _factoryMethods[controllerName] = factoryMethod;
    }


    private string ConvertToControllerName<T>()
    {
        string fullName = typeof (T).Name;
        //Cut of "Controller"
        return fullName.Substring(0, fullName.Length - 10);
    }

    public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {

        if (_factoryMethods.ContainsKey(controllerName))
            return _factoryMethods[controllerName]();

        return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);

    }
}
```

But this requires me to know which controllers to add with which dependency at compile time.
How can I get the controllers and their dependencies at runtime from their assembly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution, it is not complete generic though, since I only account for constructors with the one known dependecy.

```
Type[] controllers = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(Controller)).ToArray();
foreach (Type controller in controllers)
    {
        ConstructorInfo[] constructors = controller.GetConstructors();

        foreach (var constructor in constructors)
        {
            RegisterControllerConstructor(constructor,_MyDependecy,controller,factory);
        }
    }
}

private void RegisterControllerConstructor(ConstructorInfo constructor, MyDependecy _MyDependecy, Type controller, CustomControllerFactory factory)
    {
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        Type[] paraTypes = parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
        MethodInfo method =
            factory.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterFactoryMethod").MakeGenericMethod(controller);
        if (paraTypes.Length == 1 && paraTypes[0] == _MyDependecy.GetType())
        {
            var param = new object[1];

            Func<IController> action = () =>
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(controller, _MyDependecy) as IController;
            };

            param[0] = action;

            method.Invoke(factory, param);

        }
    }
```